# How would one attach black hole to starship in the Black hole Starship model?

Tags: black-holes, popular-science, hawking-radiation, propulsion, interstellar-travel

A [black hole starship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_starship) is a theoretical idea for enabling interstellar travel by propelling a starship by creating an artificial black hole and using a parabolic reflector to reflect its Hawking radiation.

But how do you make the black hole to move with the starship? Do you attach it magnetically? Or gravitationally?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a well-defined question, as it is about an engineering feat in a thought experiment far outside current technology.

Comment: I agree, but are thought experiments not allowed here?

Answer (score 1):

BHs can carry charge - so you squirt some electrons into it to charge it and then use an electrical charge on the parabolic reflector to couple it to the ship.

Comment: According to wikipedia you are right about the charge but I must wonder how, how does the electro-magnetic force escapes the BH if light (electro-magnetic radiation) can not escape it?

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek That's a whole different question answered elsewhere on this site